# Surprising restarts of Kubernetes pods despite restartPolicy=Never

Tags: kubernetes

I have a `cronjob` with `cronjob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy=Never`. And I am using `kubectl create job --from=cronjob/my_cronjob my_test` for manually starting an instance outside the schedule.

What I am observing is that subsequent instances of the resulting `pod` start after the first one has resulted in an error. The jobs `job.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy` and the pods' `pod.spec.restartPolicy` are also `Never` (as expected), so what could bring these restarts about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So both `cronjob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy` and `cronjob.spec.jobTemplate.spec.backoffLimit` influence such restarts. Setting the 2nd one to 0 (and keeping the 1st one at `Never`) brought about the desired behavior.